# Como pasar un valor en python a una variable para utilizarla en todo el proyecto

Tags: python

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo esta var declarada
userValidado1=StringVar()
Luego hago una consulta a la Base de datos mysql y si el usuario esta registrado le paso el valor de: UserValidado1 = True
Pero más adelante quiero utilizar esta variable para realizar otra validación y me aparece esta variable como PY_VAR4
Como le puedo hacer para que siempre tenga el valor que le pase con la Base de datos.

Gracias

Comment: Debes agregar algo del codigo que hayas intentado por tu cuenta y de ser posible un [repro] y así poder guiarte o darte una solución. Revisa el [tour] para que sepas como funciona SOes y aprendas [ask].

Comment: Lo que indica el comentario de @GmrYael es muy cierto, no obstante, una posible solución a tu problema (con la poca información que has compartido) sería definir una variable global que almacene el resultado de lo obtenido a través de SQL. espero te sirva!

Comment: Gracias CamiloMontoyaAdc,, cree la variable global como me comentaste, pero no me funciona.